# React - useEffect being called too many times while using it for "scroll to bottom" of messages list

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-hooks, render, use-effect

I'm trying to implement "scroll to bottom" function. Here is my code:

```
const messagesEndRef = useRef();    
const scrollToBottom = () => {
    if (messagesEndRef.current) {
      messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      console.log("scroll");
    }
  };
```

And I use "useEffect" to trigger it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, [messages]);
```

Here is the place where I implement the view:

```
<div className="scroll">
    <ListMessages listMessages={messages} />
    <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
</div>
```

And here is the result on browser:
[image: And here is the result on browser:]

You guys can see that the word "scroll" is printed duplicated (or more) after every message. It makes the app very slow
Could you guys have any idea to help me to solve this case?
Thank you in advance!

PS: Here is my full component

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/chat");

const Chat = () => {
  const createWebSocket = () => {
    ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
      console.log("We are connected!");
    });
    ws.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
      receiveMessage(e.data);
    });
  };
  createWebSocket();

  
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const messagesEndRef = useRef();

  const pushMessageToList = async (message, sentBy) => {
    let inputMessage = {
      id: Date.now(),
      message: message,
      sentBy: sentBy,
    };
    let listMessages = [...messages];
    listMessages.push(inputMessage);
    setMessages(listMessages);
  };
  const receiveMessage = (message) => {
    pushMessageToList(message, "chatbot");
  };
  const sendInputMessage = (message) => {
    pushMessageToList(message, "user");
    ws.send(message);
  };

  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    if (messagesEndRef.current) {
      messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      console.log("scroll");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, [messages]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // component did mount
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bg-white">
      <div className="scroll">
        <ListMessages listMessages={messages} />
        <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
      </div>
      <Input sendInputMessage={sendInputMessage} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Chat;
```

Comment: why you need messages dependency?

Comment: We need to see the full code of the component in order to help ^^

Comment: We definitely need the full component. Is it possible that the component itself is being re-rendered due to other state or prop changes?

Comment: Hi @moonwave99 and Ed Lucas, I updated full component.

Comment: Hi @abhipatil, because if I don't do that, it can not run the function scrollToBottom

Answer (score 1):

Your code is adding new listeners to the websocket on every render, that's why you are getting incremental logs.

You have to setup handlers inside a `useEffect` hook, and remove them in the cleanup function of the hook itself ([see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)), like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function onOpen() {
      console.log("We are connected!");
    }
    function onMessage({ data }) {
        setMessages([
            ...messages,
            {
                id: Date.now(),
                message: data.message,
                sentBy: 'chatbot'
            }
        ]);
    }
    ws.addEventListener("open", onOpen);
    ws.addEventListener("message",onMessage);
    return () => {
        ws.removeEventListener("open", onOpen);
        ws.removeEventListener("message", onMessage);        
    }    
}, [messages]);
```

(This hook needs the `messages` dependency, because you want to update the messages based on the previous state - I think you can do with the callback as well, without any dependency:

```js
setMessages(prevMessages => ([
    ...prevMessages,
    {
        id: Date.now(),
        message: data.message,
        sentBy: 'chatbot'
    }  
]));
```

Now you can use the scroll hook in the same hook if you are listing `messages` as dependency, or in separate one like you have now in the other case.

Your full component will look something like:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/chat");

const Chat = () => {  
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const messagesEndRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    function onOpen() {
      console.log("We are connected!");
    }
    function onMessage({ data }) {
        setMessages((prevMessages) => [
            ...prevMessages,
            {
                id: Date.now(),
                message: data.message,
                sentBy: "chatbot",
            },
        ]);
    }
    ws.addEventListener("open", onOpen);
    ws.addEventListener("message",onMessage);
    return () => {
        ws.removeEventListener("open", onOpen);
        ws.removeEventListener("message", onMessage);        
    }    
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    messagesEndRef?.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }, [messages]);


  const sendInputMessage = (message) => {
    ws.send(message);
    setMessages([
        ...messages,
        {
            id: Date.now(),
            message: data.message,
            sentBy: 'user'
        }
    ]);    
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-white">
      <div className="scroll">
        <ListMessages listMessages={messages} />
        <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
      </div>
      <Input sendInputMessage={sendInputMessage} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Comment: thank you for your help! I will try your solution